# How to modify .htaccess to serve brotli compressed static assets over gziped ones?

Tags: 7, performance, .htaccess

I'm trying to use brotli compressed static assets with Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation as detailed here, https://www.drupal.org/node/2773807. The assets are created as they should be, but they're never served because the .htaccess file doesn't know to do that.

lyncd.com has a short walkthrough, https://lyncd.com/2015/11/brotli-support-apache/, but I haven't been able to munge their code into Drupal's.

Here' the lyncd.com example:

```
    FileETag None

    <Files *.js.gz>
      AddType "text/javascript" .gz
      AddEncoding gzip .gz
    </Files>
    <Files *.css.gz>
      AddType "text/css" .gz
      AddEncoding gzip .gz
    </Files>

    <Files *.js.br>
      AddType "text/javascript" .br
      AddEncoding br .br
    </Files>
    <Files *.css.br>
      AddType "text/css" .br
      AddEncoding br .br
    </Files>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} br
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.br -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.br [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.gz [L]
```

And here's the 7.50 .htaccess bit:

```
    # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
    # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
      RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
      RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

      # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
      RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
      RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

      # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
      RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
      RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

      <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
        # Serve correct encoding type.
        Header set Content-Encoding gzip
        # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
        Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
      </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
```

With your powers combined we can make the web about 20% cooler!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give this a try

```
# Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
# Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Serve brotli compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} br
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.br -s
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.br [QSA]

  # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

  # Serve brotli compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} br
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.br -s
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.br [QSA]

  # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

  # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
  RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
  RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]
  RewriteRule \.css\.br$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
  RewriteRule \.js\.br$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

  <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
    # Serve correct encoding type.
    Header set Content-Encoding gzip
    # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
    Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch "(\.js\.br|\.css\.br)$">
    # Serve correct encoding type.
    Header set Content-Encoding br
    # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
    Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm. I took the day to play with performance, and installed Adv CSS/JS Agg, APDQC, and HTTPRL. So, thanks again! :-)